# IIS7 NOT returning HTTP 400 for a bad request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I have an MVC2 site that we perform a lot of integration tests on. Most significantly, we test the behaviour when using bad urls. For instance:

http://x.x.x.x/v1//Dy888/1/1234567815/swlocation?fv=24&sv2=3&sv3=5

(Note the two slashes after "v1".)

This should yield a HTTP 400, Bad Request, and in the development environment (VS2008) everything works as planned. But on the test environment IIS7 or MVC2 somehow sees through this and responses as if there were only one slash. It seems to be too "smart", and helps us by rewriting the request.

How can I configure my server to not be "smart", and to really respond with the correct error?

The test server is Windows Server 2008 with IIS7.

Thanks!
- Niklas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http status code 400 is defined as follows:

> The request had bad syntax or was
>   inherently impossible to be satisfied.

Having an extra forward slash in the URI (which is only a part of the request as a whole) cannot rightly be classified as a syntax error of the request, and nor does it make it impossible to satisfy the request, since the extra forward slash does not change the location pointed to by the URI.

I think that your development web server is the one behaving wrongly and that the premise for your test is wrong.

Comment: Klaus, thanks for your reply. But how is it with MVC relying on path information for the requests, isn't it really important that the path is intact? Can you clarify or explain? Thanks!

Comment: I assume that mvc sanitizes the url by removing redundant forward slashes, thus leaving the path intact. Stackoverflow uses MVC aswell. If you add any number of forward slashes to the url of this question, everything behaves normally. Which leads me to believe that MVC handles extra forward slashes by simply removing them.

Comment: Yes, that seems likely, and now I'm looking for a way to disable that sanitizing... :-) Thanks a lot!