# Why does Cassini treat URI:s with multiple slashes as a Bad Request?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I am struggling to get similar behaviour from my dev webserver [1] and my test environment [2], and am now looking at why the dev returns HTTP 400 Bad Request with this URI?

http://localhost:1234/v1//Dy888/1/1234567815/swlocation?fv=24&sv2=3&sv3=5

(Note the two slashes after "v1".)

[1] Cassini in VS2008
[2] Win Server 2008 with IIS7

Thanks in advance!
- Niklas

PS.
I started this search with this question, where I was told that the URI aforementioned should not generate a Bad Request at all:

[IIS7 NOT returning HTTP 400 for a bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450117/iis7-not-returning-http-400-for-a-bad-request)
DS.

Comment: I'm not sure that double slash is, technically, legal in HTTP URLs.

Comment: I'm not sure either, and it seems that Microsoft also disagrees with themselves, seeing that Cassini and IIS7 interprets the rules differently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not expect** similar behavior between the ASP.NET Development Server that comes built-into Visual Studio and the IIS Web Server.

They are generally two different web servers with different code bases and different feature sets. Even if they should behave similar (what they definitely don't e.g. web server features like SSL, URL Rewrite Rules, etc.) never expect them to do so.

That's just another reason Microsoft stopped the development for the ASP.NET Development Server and introduced [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) to get your development and your production web server experience again on the same page.

So my recommendation for you is:

- Stop using the ASP.NET Development Server
- Start using [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/860/iis-express/)
- **Still don't expect them to behave the same!**
  In question only a test/staging system running a real IIS instance can give you the real experience!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Martin, thanks for this! IIS Express sounds like a better option in many ways. We are moving our development into VS 2010, and I now will look into forcing the use of IIS Express instead of Cassini in that process. Hopefully, we can get more consistent results then.

Comment: BTW: I never expected Cassini and IIS to be exactly the same, but I thought there was a standard in interpreting http requests which I now have revised...

Comment: I see no reason why two web servers with two codebases could not interpret something as fundamental as a URL the same way.  But reasonable people could certainly disagree on this.